# How to provide custom model validation message in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, sails.js

How to provide custom model validation message in Sails.js?

The validation messages returned by Sails.js is not user friendly so I wanted to provide a custom validation message for rules like required, minLength etc... but don't really know how. It's not in the docs and I also checked the docs of Anchor.js w/c is the validator used by Sails but its also not there.

UPDATE:

Haven't got a response last week so I implemented my own solution, wanted to share it since it might be useful for others - [How I use custom validation messages in Sails.js](http://blog.john.mayonvolcanosoftware.com/how-i-use-custom-validation-messages-in-sails-js/)

Another alternative and better way is to use the solution of @Rifat found in the comments below :)

Another very good alternative (credits to: sfb_ ) - https://gist.github.com/basco-johnkevin/8436644

Comment: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1173#issuecomment-31327958

Comment: Can you mark your question as answered so the rest of the world can see it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Sails.js doesn't yet support using custom model validation messages, we can use these solutions:

1) [@johnkevinmbasco's solution](http://blog.john.mayonvolcanosoftware.com/how-i-use-custom-validation-messages-in-sails-js/)

2) [@sfb_'s solution](https://gist.github.com/basco-johnkevin/8436644)

3) [@rifats solution](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1173#issuecomment-31327958)

Comment: Discussion regarding @sfb_'s solution: https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/8366092

Answer (score 0):

I came up with modifying the badRequest response to overwrite the errors globally:

`/config/validationMessages.js`

```
module.exports.validationMessages = {
  password: 'password and passwordConfirm do not match'
};
```

`api/responses/badRequest.js`

```
...
// Convert validation messages
if(data && data.code !== 'E_VALIDATION') {
  _.forEach(data.invalidAttributes, function(errs, fld) {
    data.invalidAttributes[fld] = errs.map(function(err) {
      if(sails.config.validationMessages[err.rule]) {
        err.message = sails.config.validationMessages[err.rule];
      }
      return err;
    });
  });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [sails-hook-validation](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-hook-validation)

And made some improvements in responses/badRequest.js

```
.....
// If the user-agent wants JSON, always respond with JSON
if (req.wantsJSON) {
    if (data.code == 'E_VALIDATION' && data.Errors) {
        return res.jsonx(data.Errors);
    }
    return res.jsonx(data);
}
.....
```