# Sails js :: How to add custom validation error

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Like Rails is there any way to add custom error message to validator?

Like:

```
if(this.password != this.passwordConfirmation){
   this.errors.add('password', {rule: 'invalid'})
}
```

Comment: Here is my answer in similar question.
[my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33626361/2467036)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am trying to do same in Sails 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom validations on your models. Or create custom objects and inject them into your models to resusable code. Its actually in the docs!

http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Validations.html?q=custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom config file for error handling. You can reach that global config object by `sails.config.error` for example. Advantage of this solution is, that you can access this object in services and other places, where you have no access to the `res` object.

Next step would be creating a policy which would pass this config error object to `res.locals`. Or it could be handled in a response file, but I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Sails.js **does not support custom validation messages**. But there's a workaround, using hooks.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations#?custom-validation-rules

Says the official site.