# sailsjs remove confidential data after validation

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am using sailsjs (version 0.11.0)

My user model is defined as below.

```
module.exports = {

  types:{
    password: function(password){
      return password === this.confirmPassword;
    }
  },
  attributes: {
    password: {
      type:'string',
      required: true,
      minLength: 6,
      password: true
    }
  }
}
```

if my password is not equal to confirmPassword, I am getting message as `"\"password\" validation rule failed for input: '123456'"`

but I don't want my api server to send the input `password` back again.

I have tried the below script but it is not working.

```
password: function(password){
  if(password === this.confirmPassword) {
    return true;
  }
  else{
    password = null;
    return false;
  }
}
```

How to remove the password from the validation message? How to add custom validation message?

That question might be about some different version. It's been an year, there might be solution in the newer version.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768102/how-to-provide-custom-model-validation-message-in-sails-js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you probably want to use the toJson method http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json

Comment: I am talking about the validation message with password. `"\"password\" validation rule failed for input: '123456'"`